# Having express.js or node accept an http connection over port 443

Tags: node.js, ssl, express

I have a REST API built with node that communicates over SSL. The server is built uses express and makes use of vhosts and cors. I have recently added a listener on port 80 as well so I can force HTTPS. As I test, I tried to access http://manage.domain.com:443/ but the request just hangs. Neither listeners seem to accept it. All I want to do is redirect that request to https.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you already know this, but you'll need an https server (duh) to serve the HTTPS content.  It doesn't matter what port you run it on; 443 is just the default port for HTTPS.  If you want HTTP requests to redirect to HTTPS, you'll need both an http and an https server.  Here's an example of how your app file should look:

```
var http = require('http'),
    https = require('https'),
    express = require('express')
    fs = require('fs');

var domain = 'localhost';

var app = express();
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    // redirect to HTTPS
    res.redirect('https://' + domain + req.path);
});

http.createServer(app).listen(80, function(){
    console.log('HTTP listening on port 80');
});

var appSecure = express();
// configure your app here

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('ssl_key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl_cert.crt'),
};

https.createServer(options, appSecure).listen(443, function(){
    console.log('HTTPS listening on port 443');
});
```

Obviously, you will need your SSL key and certificate to make this work.

As you probably know, most systems require elevated privileges to open a port less than 1025; so if you use port 80 and port 443, you'll have to run the app server with elevated privileges (if you're running on OSX/Linux/BSD, just do `sudo node app.js`).

Comment: That is exactly the setup I have. In my case, If I try http://localhost:443/ then the request just keeps loading. Notice that my servers are http on 80 and https on 443 but I'm trying to make the client access http on 443. I don't want to send any data, just want to redirect the user to https/443

Comment: Ah.  Unfortunately, you're not going to be able to do that out of the box with Node: you would have to essentially write your own module (`httpAndHttps`), and that would be a...substantial effort.  This discussion may help you, though: http://serverfault.com/questions/359461/apache-answer-both-http-and-https-on-the-same-port

Comment: You can just put a load balancer to offload ssl in front of node, then at node's side its all http

Comment: Yeah was afraid of that. Can't be done with node alone. Maybe a proxy in front of node. Makes sense to have anyway.

Comment: Xerri, I think you're a little confused about what it is you want, exactly.  _Multiplexing_ HTTP and HTTPS means that the same endpoint (host/port) can speak both HTTP and HTTPS.  If a client makes a request in plaintext, it answers in HTTP.  If a client makes an SSL request, it responds in HTTPS.  _Redirecting_ is an entirely different mechanism.

Comment: A load balancer can certainly help you redirect, but I don't know of any that will do multiplexing.  IMO, multiplexing is a bad idea anyway.  Redirecting is really the way to go: it sends a clear message to the client that they need to be communicating over a secure channel.  Multiplexing quietly allows insecure communication.

Comment: Yes I am not looking for multiplexing. I already redirect my HTTP request to HTTPS (note that I only do this with cookies set as SECURE so that cookies are NEVER transmitted over HTTP). Currently if you build and HTTPS application with express and try localhost:443, you will not get a reply. The browser just keeps waiting, not even a timeout. I just want to fix that one request. Try your code and you'll understand what I mean.

Comment: That's not the case for me, Xerri.  I just tried my example, and it works fine on `https://localhost` and `https://localhost:443`....